# get contract A address from contract B

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to get the address of the deployed contract `A` but creating a new A `A first = new A();` generate a new contract with a new address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;



contract A {

  address public contract_A_address =address(this);
  address public owner_A = msg.sender;



}


contract B {

  address public contract_B_address =address(this);
  address public owner_B = msg.sender;

  A first = new A();


  function Get_first_Address() public view returns(address){
    return address(first);
    }

    function Get_Contract_A_Address() public view returns(address){
    return ??? ;
    }

}
```

The output needed for `Get_Contract_A_Address()` of contract B should be the same as `contract_A_address` of contract A

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the purpose of using :

> A first = new A();

Because A is another contract, deployed before B, inheritance can be use :

```
contract B is A { ...
#then the variable contract_A_address is available
```

OR contract_A_address can be put as parameter in the constructor of B for being filled during the deployment process :

```
contract B {
contructor(address contract_A_address) public { ...
```